# How can I have centered links and other right/left-positioned ones in a navbar?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a navbar composed by 5 links.Three of them need to be centered, and another two of them needs to be right positioned ones.However, i'm getting the following, where the three "centered" links are actually not centered.The two right positioned links pulls the three centered ones a bit to the left.Could anyone help me center the three links?

[image: navbar with three "centered" links and two right-positioned ones]

Here is my code (index):

```
<nav class="navbar " style="margin-bottom: 0px;border:1px solid blue;" >

          <!-- header -->
          <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#barra-navegacao">
              <span class="sr-only">alternar navegação</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

          </div><!-- /header -->

          <!-- navbar -->
          <div id="barra-navegacao" class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="border:1px dashed red;" >

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="border:1px solid red;">


              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>  

            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="border:1px solid red;">

              <li><a href="inscrevase.php">Inscrever-se</a></li>
              <li  class="<?= $erro == 1 ? 'open':'' ?>">
                <a id="entrar" data-target="#" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Entrar</a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="entrar">
                  <div class="col-md-12">

                      <h3>Você possui uma conta?</h3>

                      <br />

                    <form method="post" action="validar_acesso.php" id="formLogin">

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="campo_usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuário" />
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control red" id="campo_senha" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" />
                      </div>

                      <button type="buttom" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_login">Entrar</button>

                      <br/><br/>

                    </form>

                    <?php
                      if($erro == 1){
                        echo '<font color="#FF0000"> Usuário e ou senha inválido(s)</font>';
                      }
                    ?>


                  </div><!-- /col-md-12 -->
                </ul><!-- dropdown-menu -->
              </li>

            </ul>

          </div><!-- /navbar --> 
    </nav><!--/nav  -->
```

And here is my css-style file:

```
    *{
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background: url('imagens/airplane.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;/*imagem fixa no fundo*/
    background-size: cover;/*evita que com o zoom o background fique menor*/
}

.navbar{
    background-color: black;

}



.icon-bar{
    background:white !important;

}


/*remove o gap entre os links e a navbar*/
.navbar-nav li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

/*alinhamento da navbar ao centro*/
.navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

.navbar-collapse{
    text-align: center;
}
/*fim do alinhamento da navbar ao centro*/


.navbar a{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;

}

.navbar a:hover{
    background-color: gray;
    color: red;
}

.navbar a:focus {
    background-color: gray;
    color: black;
}

.vertical-line{
    width: 2px;
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.group1{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 0.1fr 1fr;
}

.group2{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.attack-airplane{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 40%;/*observe que o tamanho é igual ao do texto*/
}

.man-shadow{
    width: 40%;
}

.text-attack-airplane{
    width: 40%;/*observe que o tamanho é igual ao da imagem*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    border:1px solid red;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    color: white;
}

.text{
    text-align: justify;
}

/*barra com links de midias sociais*/
#social-media{
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

/*textos abaixo das 3 imagens*/
#pictures p{
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 0 30px;
}



#pictures img{
    width: 235px;
    height: 214px;

}

/*efeito de aproximação das imagens*/
#pictures img:hover{
    width: 235px;
    height: 214px;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: all 1s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 676px){

    .group1{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }

    .group2{
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }

    .vertical-line{
        display: none;
    }

    .attack-airplane{
        width: 80%;
    }

    .text-attack-airplane{
        width: 80%;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the problems you're facing is the browser is computing the placement of the two `<ul>` together - you are not applying any CSS to force the browser to do otherwise.

By using absolute positioning on the right-aligned `<ul>` you essentially remove it's footprint from the layout. Here is my suggestion:

```
div.navbar-collapse {
    position:relative;
    }
ul.navbar-nav:nth-of-type(1) {
    display:table;
    margin:0 auto;
    }
ul.navbar-nav:nth-of-type(2) {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    }
```

as shown on this snippet: (also on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zmYqaG))

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding:0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.navbar {
  background-color: black;
}
.navbar-header {
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
}
.navbar-collapse {
  position:relative;
}
/*remove o gap entre os links e a navbar*/
.navbar-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
/*alinhamento da navbar ao centro*/
.navbar-nav:nth-of-type(1) {
  display:table;
  margin:0 auto;
}
/*fim do alinhamento da navbar ao centro*/
.navbar a {
  display:block;
  color:white;
  padding:8px;
}
.navbar li ~ li a {
  margin-left:16px;
}
.navbar a:hover{
  background-color: gray;
  color:red;
}
.navbar a:focus {
  background-color:gray;
  color:black;
}
.navbar-nav:nth-of-type(2) {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  border-color:yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar" style="border:10px solid blue;" >

<!-- header -->
<div class="navbar-header">
|
</div><!-- /header -->

<!-- navbar -->
<div id="barra-navegacao" class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="border:1px dashed red;" >
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center" style="border:1px solid red;">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>  
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="border:1px solid red;">
    <li><a href="inscrevase.php">Inscrever-se</a></li>
    <li  class="<?= $erro == 1 ? 'open':'' ?>">
    <a id="entrar" data-target="#" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Entrar</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar --> 
</nav><!--/nav  -->
```

I removed a number of your HTML elements and CSS entries for clarity.

Comment: thank you @aequalsb!I've only have set position absolute to solve, as you mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

How about if my code was the following (removing the two following lines), how could i solve my problem?:

```
<nav class="navbar" style="border:10px solid blue;" >

<!-- header -->
<div class="navbar-header">
|
</div><!-- /header -->

<!-- navbar -->
<div id="barra-navegacao" class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="border:1px dashed red;" >
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center" style="border:1px solid red;">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

  </ul> /*THIS LINE REMOVED*/
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="border:1px solid red;"> /*THIS LINE REMOVED TOO*/

    <li><a href="inscrevase.php">Inscrever-se</a></li>
    <li  class="<?= $erro == 1 ? 'open':'' ?>">
    <a id="entrar" data-target="#" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Entrar</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar --> 
</nav><!--/nav  -->
```